# How to use the argument v in the given function

Tags: python, function

```
def do_twice(f):
  """
  This function calls any function object that is passed to it twice
  """
  f()
  f()

def print_spam():
  print('spam')

do_twice(print_spam)
```

So I was able to write the above code .

Now I was asked to modify do_twice function so that it takes two arguments - a function object and a value, and calls the function twice, passing value as argument in this format:

```
def do_twice(f, v):
"""
This function calls any function object that is passed to it twice passing v as the argument

Input:
  f: function object
  v: value
"""
### Write your code here
```

I am not able to understand how to use the argument v inside the function

Comment: You already know how to use a passed in argument ``f`` (directly as ``f``), how to call a passed in function (namely ``f()``) and how to pass arguments when calling a function (``do_twice(print_spam)``). What specific problem do you have using the passed in arguments ``f`` and ``v``, in order to pass ``v`` when calling it ``f``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the function take two arguments:

```
def do_twice(f, v):
```

Then you can call it with the function and value:

```
do_twice(some_func, "a string")
```

For example:

```
def do_twice(f, v):
    f(v)
    f(v)

def print_word(word):
    print(word)

do_twice(print_word, 'spam')
```